# Extjs how to decode a json string?

Tags: extjs, decode, json

I have to decode JSON with `Extjs 4`:

I have used `Ext.decode(string, true)`, but it doesn't work 'cause my string is a JSON with a JSON string (escaped) inside... like this:

```
var string = '{
    success: true,
    rows: [{
        "id": 33,
        "defaultset": 1,
        "name": "Generico",
        "jsonfields": "[{\"name\":\"cm:addressees\",\"title\":\"Destinatari\",\"description\":\"Destinatari\",\"dataType\":\"d:text\",\"url\":\"\/api\/property\/cm_addressees\"}]",
        "eliminato": 0
    }]
}';
```

as you can see the field `jsonfields` is a JSON string. When I use

```
Ext.decode(string, true);
```

nothing happens neither error.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You may try like this:

```
var string = '{success:true, rows:[{"id":33,"defaultset":1,"name":"Generico","jsonfields":"[{\\"name\\":\\"cm:addressees\\",\\"title\\":\\"Destinatari\\",\\"description\\":\\"Destinatari\\",\\"dataType\\":\\"d:text\\",\\"url\\":\\"/api/property/cm_addressees\\"}]","eliminato":0}]}';

var decodedString = Ext.decode(string);
console.log(decodedString);
```

that's a little bit tricky. If you remove safe parameter you will see that your json misses `\` in your `jsonfields` thats because your string is in `'` quotes and one `\` does the job for it but you want something different... so you have to double it.

[fiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/H4QEP/)

Comment: Sorry I have a string variable x, when I write console.log(x) -> I get this: "{success:true, rows:[{"id":33,"defaultset":1,"name":"Generico","jsonfields":"[{\\"name\\":\\"cm:addressees\\",\\"title\\":\\"Destinatari\\",\\"description\\":\\"Destinatari\\",\\"dataType\\":\\"d:text\\",\\"url\\":\\"/api/property/cm_addressees\\"}]","eliminato":0}]}" , with double quote... Ext.Decode doesn't work... any suggests?

Answer (score 1):

It does work, for example I am getting my Json from the server,

```
websocket.onmessage = function(event)
```

from the websocket actually and later when I want to decode my json,

```
var json = Ext.decode(event.data);
```

and where I need my string for example

```
json.map.MessageType
```

My json looks like this:

```
mpty":false,"map":{"MessageText":"Ciao, how are you?","MessageType":"IN"},"hashtable":{"MessageText":"Ciao, how are you?","MessageType":"IN"},"persistData":{"MessageText":"Ciao, how are you?","MessageType":"IN"}}
```

Hope this helps, cheers!